# python: looking for a way to pass a number to a function with a string

Tags: python-2.7

Can you suggest a clean way to pass a string that maps to a number. I want to make it easier for script writers using the command, so they don’t need to remember the actual numerical values. For example:

```
def writeTempCommand(value):
#send a command to the thermostat, high, medium, or low
# high =100
# medium = 50
# low = 0
    # the actual format must look like this
    writeTemp(value)

#but I want to call the command like this for ease of use
writeTempCommand.high
writeTempCommand.medium
writeTempCommand.low
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary

```
temperatures = {"high": 100, "medium": 50, "low": 0}
```

Now when you need to retrieve those values you use it like a list but the index is the string itself.

```
print temperatures["high"]
>>> 100
input = "low"
print temperatures[input]
>>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `dict` object, or you could pass it in, or you could use a class:

`dict`:

```
>>> temperatures = {"high": 100, "medium": 50, "low": 0}
>>> temperatures["medium"]
50
>>> temperatures["low"]+temperatures["high"]
100
>>>
```

Passing it in:

```
>>> def writeTemp(value):
...     temperatures = {"high": 100, "medium": 50, "low": 0}
...     try:
...         return temperatures[value]
...     except KeyError:
...         return None
... 
>>> writeTemp('high')
100
>>> writeTemp('nothing')
>>> writeTemp('low')
0
>>>
```

Or using a class:

```
>>> class writeTemp:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.high = 100
...             self.medium = 50
...             self.low = 0
... 
>>> temp = writeTemp()
>>> temp.high
100
>>> temp.medium
50
>>> temp.low
0
>>> writeTemp().low
0
>>>
```